# 502 NGINX bad gateway and httpd.service failed on CentOS 7 and plesk

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, nginx, centos-7, plesk

After trying to install google pagespeed and mistakenly tried to turn on pagespeed_ap24 at plesk apache webserver settings, the settings caused an error during apache webserver settings update and unticked all my apache modules and hence causing all my websites to be 502, also with httpd.service failed. I am new to this and I do not even know which modules I should turn on or off.

[(very large) picture of current screen of my apache web server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f43ku.jpg)

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have solve the issue by merely commenting out loading of pagespeed_ap24 in config.modules.d/00-base.conf

and restarted nginx and apache